# Inverse (write_only) SerializerMethodField in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In the Django REST Framework, is there an "inverse" of the `SerializerMethodField` which is `write_only`? What I am looking for is a `Serializer` that will set a field on the model based on the value returned by a method.

I do not want this field to render a widget however.

Comment: In this case you probably need a [parser](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers), not a serializer.

Comment: @PauloScardine While it may be possible to do is this way (for example subclassing the existing parser, calling the super `parse` method and then inserting the desired value into the parsed data), I would need to to do this for each style of parsing (JSON, YAML, etc). What I want to inject occurs after the raw data is decoded.

Comment: Ok, how about a mixin that overrides `pre_save` or `post_save` on the Generic views? Then you just have to include that mixin when declaring your views.

Comment: The problem with `pre_save` is that it gets called after the model serializer calls `is_valid` which means the value can't be used for validation of other fields. It also means I need to re-implement validation in the view if I want to validate this "injected" value.

Comment: Do you have to access the object when determining the value? Wich data is the result based on?

Comment: The value to be injected is not a function of object itself. The value  is based on other characteristics of the request.

Comment: Looks there is no convenient hook for doing what you want in rest_framework. You can always use a Django middleware...

Comment: The closest solution that I came up with is to add a Field with `write_only=True`, `read_only=False`, `required=False` and then to set the `init_data` for that Field in the Viewset's `get_serializer`. I hide the widget (sort-of) by having the `render` method for the Field's `widget` return `''`. The problems with this solution are 1) it only hides the input field, but not its label in the HTML API and 2) I have to put some logic on when to set init_data (only certain POSTs).

Comment: The field+label can be fully remove by replacing the Serializer used using a predicate like this in the `get_serializer_class` method: `if not hasattr(self.request, 'accepted_renderer') or (hasattr(self.request, 'accepted_renderer') and self.request.accepted_renderer.format) == 'api' and self.request.method == 'GET':`

Answer (score 0):

I'd try creating a `WritableField` subclass that implements `from_native` to perform the transformation you require. Make it `write_only` — that should do what you need, I think :)

Comment: Will that still render the input widget on the browsable API?